# Error in using c-code in python

Tags: python, c, dll

I am trying to use C-code in Python. I complied the c code in linux and using .so file in windows as I found it on internet. My code of python is given below:

```
from ctypes import *
add1 = CDLL('./adder.dll')
sum_c = add1.add_int(5,4)
```

The C-code is a simple adder. This works fine with Python in linux but I get the following error in windows:

```
 test.py line 6, in <module>
    add1 = CDLL('./adder.dll')
  File "..\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Please let me know what is the problem.

Comment: Did you recompile the dll for windows? Or did you build in your linux environment then just copy the dll over?

Comment: I just copied it from linux. 
How can I compile dll in windows?

Comment: I also created DLL in windows using Cygwin. The result is same.

Comment: You have to build your code in *Cygwin* and run it with your *Python* for *Cygwin*. If you want to run it with native *Win* *Python*, you should use other tools (e.g. *VStudio*) in order to build it. Note that shared objects are not interchangable among different *OS*es (espacially *Win* and *Lnx*).